# Adding Select All in Material UI multiselect and displaying the values in select option

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material UI and trying to integrate a select all option in material multiselect.
I have a array of object

```
const names = [
{ id: 0, name: "Oliver Hansen" },
{ id: 1, name: "Van Henry" },
{ id: 2, name: "April Tucker" }
];
```

I'm iterating over this array and displaying the value in multiselect.
Below is the code for Multiselect

```
 <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
      id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      value={personName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<Input />}
      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      <MenuItem
        value="all"
        classes={{
          root: isAllSelected ? classes.selectedAll : ""
        }}
      >
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Checkbox
            classes={{ indeterminate: classes.indeterminateColor }}
            checked={isAllSelected}
            indeterminate={
              personName.length > 0 && personName.length < names.length
            }
          />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
          classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }}
          primary="Select All"
        />
      </MenuItem>
      {names.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
          <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(item.id) > -1} />
          <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

In the select option i'm giving value as id and text as name, But when i select any option it will display me the value in place of name.

Which is correct in one sense but i want to display only name in the select field not its id which i associated to the value.

Also selectAll is acting as a indiviual option not selection all the values.

[Here is the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-kalam-td713?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have id you can find object which belongs to it and then use only the name.

```
renderValue={
    (selected) => 
        names.filter( name => selected.includes(name.id) )
            .map( record => record.name )
            .join(", ")
}
```

Comment: what about select all ?

Comment: Can you also suggest on selectAll

Comment: @AtalShrivastava check this https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-fast-dz088?file=/src/App.js

Comment: 1 doubt, on selecting select all it will return empty array on deselect it will return array with all values ?

Comment: When you click select all it return array with all id's, and when deselect all it return empty array.

Comment: but currently oppsite is happening. On selecting All it will return empty array on deselecting it will return array with all id's

Comment: I added useEffect to example to check result and in my case seems to work fine

Comment: can you save that code to sandbox example